# UICollectionView: How to get the header view for a section?

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

There is a method to get a cell by `indexPath` (`UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:`). But I can"t find a method to get one of the supplementary views like a header or footer, after it has been created. Any ideas?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### UPDATE

As of iOS 9, you can use [`-[UICollectionView supplementaryViewForElementKind:atIndexPath:]`](http://mayoff-imac.local:53048/Dash/xxeuovbv/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/supplementaryViewForElementKind:atIndexPath:) to get a supplementary view by index path.

### ORIGINAL

Your best bet is to make your own dictionary mapping index paths to supplementary views.  In your `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` method, put the view into the dictionary before returning it.  In your `collectionView:didEndDisplayingSupplementaryView:forElementOfKind:atIndexPath:`, remove the view from the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the didEndDisplayingSupplementaryView method! I missed that one.

Comment: Is there a good reason that the UICollectionView doesn't offer an API for this?

Comment: I am pretty sure Apple will refactor UICollectionView stuff to make it more similar than UITableView, lot of features are still missing

Comment: The reason is that CollectionView is more generic than a table view. With CollectionViews, there are only cells, supplementary views and decoration views.

Headers and footers are actually implemented as supplementary views: so actually it wouldn't make sense for Apple to explicitly offer an API for what really is a *specific* kind of supplementary view.

Comment: iOS 9 introduces `func supplementaryViewForElementKind(elementKind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView` :)

Comment: Also added iOS 9 public func visibleSupplementaryViewsOfKind(elementKind: String) -> [UICollectionReusableView]

Comment: what should be the `indexpath`? If I have a header in `first section`, so the index path would be `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]`?

Answer (score 31):

I would like to share my insight of the solution provided by **rob mayoff** but I can't post comment so I am putting it here:

For every one of you that tried to keep reference of the supplementary views being used by a collection view but who run into issues of loosing track too early because of

```
collectionView:didEndDisplayingSupplementaryView:forElementOfKind:atIndexPath:
```

being called too many times, try using an NSMapTable instead of a dictionary.

I use

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSMapTable *visibleCollectionReusableHeaderViews;
```

created like this:

```
_visibleCollectionReusableHeaderViews = [NSMapTable mapTableWithKeyOptions:NSMapTableStrongMemory valueOptions:NSMapTableWeakMemory];
```

so that when you are keeping a reference to a supplementary view:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ( ... )
    [_visibleCollectionReusableHeaderViews setObject:cell forKey:indexPath];
```

it keeps only a WEAK reference to it in the NSMapTable and it keeps it AS LONG AS the object is not deallocated!

You don't need anymore to remove the view from

```
collectionView:didEndDisplayingSupplementaryView:forElementOfKind:atIndexPath:
```

as the NSMapTable will lose the entry as soon as the view is deallocated.

Comment: Thank you for this great idea. It led me to NSHashTable which allows me to keep weak references to the header views without needing to keep keys in synch when sections are moved within the table.

Comment: @DavidU if you don’t have keys, how do you find the supplementary view you need? Or do you have another means of identifying them?

Comment: @DavidU I ended up overriding `-applyLayoutAttributes` and grabbing a copy of the index path, and then iterating over views in the hash table and comparing against the index path.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg I give each header a unique tag and then enumerate over them in a headerWithTag method.

Comment: @DavidU cool, sounds like we have similar approaches. Also: collection view really ought to have API for this :\

Answer (score 9):

First thing you have to do is check the box "Section Header" in the collection view's attribute inspector. Then add a collection reusable view just like you added your cell to the collection view, write an identifier and make a class for it if you need to. Then implement the method:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

From there do exactly like you did with cellForItemAtIndexPath
Its also important to specify if its a header or footer you are coding about:

```
if([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader])
{
    Header *header = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"headerTitle" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //modify your header
    return header;
}

else
{

    EntrySelectionFooter *footer = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"entryFooter" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //modify your footer
    return footer;
}
```

use indexpath.section to know what section this is in
also note that Header and EntrySelectionFooter are custom subclasses of UICollectionReusableView that I made

Comment: `kind` is an `NSString`. It should be compared using `if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader])`, not `==`.

Answer (score 4):

This method is often enough to serve the purpose of reloading on-screen supplementary views:

```
collectionView.visibleSupplementaryViews(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader)
```

Comment: Swift 4:
collectionView.visibleSupplementaryViews(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader)

Comment: also work uikti to swiftui ,in wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI use UIKit of UICollectionView

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UICollectionView, context: Context) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
            flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
            flowLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
            flowLayout.sectionInset = .init(top: 5, left: 20, bottom: 5, right: 20)
            flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(self.changeUI.numColum)) - 1, height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(self.changeUI.numColum)) - 1)
            
            uiView.setCollectionViewLayout(flowLayout, animated: true)
            
            
            let headers_views = uiView.visibleSupplementaryViews(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader)
            
            headers_views.forEach { hv in
                if let button = hv.viewWithTag(101) {
                    button.isHidden = isEdit
                }
            }
            //            // re lay out
            //            if  viewsOfHeader.count == self.parent.data.count {
            //                let view =  viewsOfHeader[section]
            //                if let button = view.viewWithTag(101) {
            //                    button.isHidden = self.parent.isEdit
            //                }
            //            }
            
            
            uiView.reloadData()
            
        }
```

use collectionView.visibleSupplementaryViews(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader)